# ListView and variable height items causes scroll problems

Tags: android, listview, scroll, height, adapter

I have a `ListView` that I use to scroll a list of fields, a text and a photo. **Both heights are dynamic**: The textview can contain a very long paragraph or just a sentence, and the image is scaled to fit width, so the height is variable (you can see the photo). Some items even don't have an image.
[image]
This makes the items very heterogeneous in height. There is one item that can be 2 screens long, while another just one line of text.

I have it working etc.. but **when I scroll upwards, as recycled views are inserted at the top, the scroll position jumps approximately the size of the new child. Scroll down works perfect...**

I understand more or less why, obviously the recycled views are totally different in size, and this makes some scrolling algorythm fail, wherever it may be.

I have read about overriding `itemType()` and `itemTypeCount`, but I don't know if it's related to my problem. In the tests I did it didn't (magically) worked.

Can this be fixed easily, any trick or magic requestLayout here and there?

There's a guy suggesting to write a View recycler to fix this: question [listview scrolls quite junky when therre are different row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584554/listview-scrolls-quite-junky-when-therre-are-different-row-heights?rq=1)

Would writing a `View recycler` be as terribly complicated as it sounds?

Sorry for the abstract question..

Comment: Please post your adapter layouts and the adapters getView code.

Comment: post your xml code...

Comment: @rupps How did you make your item height variable? I need such a list!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi, nothing special, just set "wrap to content" to items, but you will face this problem

Comment: I don't do anything strange in getView, just avoiding to post it because it is very big and full of stuff not related to this problem, the problem is just the inflated converted views are re-converted to a new one with very different height, and in this case the scrolling jumps. By the way, if the new cell has "not that different" size, the scroll works OK. There are no layout XMLs, the views are 100% dynamic.

Comment: Hi have you found any solution to your problem? i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

Just remember the height of the ImageView and the TextView, and then when your views are being recycled, set the height for those views from the getView method in your ListAdapter (you need to extend BaseAdapter for this).

So you have a List of objects with your data (some text, maybe an image URL, etc). Add an integer field called imageHeight. When you load the image for a list item for the first time, save the height of the ImageView to that integer field in the data object associated with that list item. Then, in getView in your ListAdapter, set the height of the ImageView to the value of imageHeight.

This will make your adapter return a view which has the proper height. Of course, this only works if you already know the height of the image/text you're about to load. This will be true if you're scrolling up, since those items have already been loaded.

Comment: The problem is, even if know each element height, as all elements have different heights, I can't do a setHeight() with the previous height, it will be incorrect for sure (for example, the recycled element was just a short message and the new one has a 400px height image) I have solved this creating several item types with 50px intervals, so getItemType(position) returns a type depending on its content height. If the item type height step is kept sufficiently small (in my case I calculated 50px) there won't be jumps when scrolling up !

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you solved it. However, your method seems to only work for a set number of heights. What I'm suggesting is actually saving the height of the the ImageView/TextView inside the *data* object. So if you have an ArrayList of data objects of a class that you actually wrote yourself, you can add integer fields to that class to remember them, so when it comes time to recycle them, simply set the height of the ImageView/TextView along with setting the actual content. This works for any arbitrary height.

Comment: It's a nice idea,but the problem is,the mess is all ListView's internals: Even setting the height as you suggest, the scroll jumps the same, because the internal scroll routines expect similar (or close) heights. The scroll tries to compensate height discrepancies, and corrects the position by the difference between the height before recycling, and the new height. With my (hacky) method, I guarantee that differences in height won't be more than 50 pixels, which the Android scrolling routines seem able to compensate. Mind the problem only happens if the new height is very diff. to the old one!

Comment: Well, I use this technique in my app, and scrolling up doesn't jump even one pixel, given that the content in those views has already been loaded, so I thought I'd share it, even though it's an old question. Anyway, I'm glad you solved it already!

Comment: i'll double-check it! wrote this out of my head, as u say it's an old question. But Idk if I understand your method correctly: for example, if I have an incoming row that's just been recycled exiting the screen upwards, imagine it's 2500px tall(500px image + 1500px text), then I recycle it for the downwards-entering view that's, say, no image and 30px text, when and to who do I assign the height? I suppose you mean when I construct it in getView? But you mean assigning heights to both image & text? or to the containing layout?what if there's no image(vis=GONE),scroll jumps the same in my exp.

Comment: That's correct, you set your heights when you construct the view in the `getView()` method of your adapter. And yes, in your case, you will have to assign the heights to both the TextView and the ImageView, probably by doing something like `imageView.getLayoutParams().height = rowData.imageViewHeight`. This will ensure that the heights are set before the view is even shown on the screen. And I think you could just set the view's height to zero if there's no image.

Comment: will check it for sure & accept your answer if it works! it can get a little messy because at view construction time I don't always know the heights (images are lazily loaded and might not yet be lru-cached / downloaded) so the first iteration will have to either go blind with the image size or pre-fetch metadata about future rows images (bitmapOptions.inDecodeBounds) to learn about the size. Thanx for your help!

Comment: Well usually if the images and text aren't loaded, the user will be scrolling down, so there's no problem there. If you're scrolling up, mist of the stuff should have been loaded unless the user flick scrolled. In any case, you can mix it with your existing solution as a fallback in case something wasn't loaded. And no problem, I hope that helps!

Comment: I have also used the method suggested by Hassan successfully so I confirm it works. One more tip which doesn't necessarily suite the OP's situation but might be helpful for somebody else reading this: it's possible to set a minimum height for a View which can be used to make the list item view to take the required amount of space. For example in a list of mine an item view was a `WebView` inside a `LinearLayout`. In `getView()` I set the minimum height for the `LinearLayout` equal to the cached item height. This makes the item view take enough space until the `WebView` loads its content.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cache the images (in WeakHashMap) in getView and then the scroll up wont need to reload the image, which cause the ugly height recalculation...

Answer (score -5):

Don't use the convertView of the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) method.

You have to inflate the row everytime the getView is called. It will make the scrolling somewhat slow but your issue will be solved.

Comment: Hi! That's indeed a solution, but the performance would be terrible!! This is a generic adapter that is used a lot, so I can't afford to do it because it would affect the app a lot.

Comment: Terrible advice, did you try it by yourself?